# Old novel featuring travel between planets via tubes that were located at the poles in pools of mercury

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a sci-fi novel over 30 years ago.  It featured travel between planets via tubes that were located at the poles in pools of mercury.  I have never been able to find it since.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. By "poles," did you mean the North and South poles? Also, by "travel between planets," did you mean travel from one planet to another (i.e. inter-planetary travel), or travel from one pole of a planet to the opposite pole of the same planet (i.e. intra-planetary travel)?

Answer (score 15):

[Star Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Bridge) by Jack Williamson and James Gunn. It was published in 1955, so it was old when you read it thirty years ago. The book has been reprinted numerous times and [you can see all the covers on the ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?11587).

The introduction says:

> Empire ...
>
> The greatest empire of them all, spanning the light years, gathering in the stars like a patient fisherman with a golden net.
>
> Eron. Poor, barren planet, mother of greatness. Name of empire.
>
> World after world. Star after star. Build a model. Scale it: one million miles to the inch. An Earth-size planet would not contain it.
>
> But if you had that model and looked closely—closer yet—you would see the stars joined together by a delicately shimmering golden tracery like an iridescent web.
>
> For an empire is communications, and communications is an empire. The fact of the Eron Empire was the Tubes. Each gleaming strand in the vast web was a Tube, a bridge between the stars, over the wide, dark river of space.
>
> Star bridge ...

The ends of the *Tubes* are located at the poles and float in a pool of mercury so they can remain stationary while the planet rotates below them:

> He planned what he would do when he reached Eron. The Tube would take him to one of the Terminal caps at the poles, a cap bristling with Tubes. The caps didn’t rotate with Eron. If they did, the Tubes would soon be twisted together like spaghetti. The broad, spiked caps floated in a shallow pool of mercury. They turned in the opposite direction of Eron’s rotation, or, rather, motors kept them motionless while Eron turned underneath.

Comment: So this story is presumably set in a parallel universe where planets and galaxies don’t have varying orbits and are always stationary in relation to each other?

Comment: As opposed to the parallel universe, @JanusBahsJacquet, where planets are connected to each other with tubes anchored in motorized pools of mercury? :)